# CSS Issue Causing White Space at Top of Page on Safari Mobile (iOS)

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

There is a horizontal white bar, approximately 15px in height, across the top of every one of my pages when viewing my website's mobile version. Here is the relevant CSS code and HTML markup:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#navigation {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #009245;
}

#content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="navigation" class="navigationtext">
      <h2><a href="">domain</a><br> the home page of First Last</h2>
      <p><a href="/about/">About</a></p>
      <p><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></p>
      <p><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></p>
      <div class="copyright">Copyright</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Content/text goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried many combinations of CSS properties (primarily "margin" and "padding") and have spent a lot of time searching the Web. Nothing seems to work.

Please let me know if you need anything. I will be checking this thread regularly tonight.

Comment: Is this issue only on safari mobile? Did you check other browsers?

Comment: I just downloaded Firefox for iOS (I'd been meaning to do that) and can confirm that the issue affects Firefox as well.

Comment: Check answer may be it will help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign `h2` `margin:0`. and in `body` `margin:0` and `padding:0`.
Because by default `h2` tag have `margin` inspect `h2` tag.

```
.navigationtext h2 {
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;     /*Added*/
  margin: 0;      /*Added*/
}

.navigationtext h2 {
  margin: 0px;          /*Added css for h2 tag*/
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#navigation {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #009245;
}

#content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navigation" class="navigationtext">
    <h2><a href="">domain</a><br> the home page of First Last</h2>
    <p><a href="/about/">About</a></p>
    <p><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></p>
    <p><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></p>
    <div class="copyright">Copyright</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content/text goes here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, LKG! I only had to assign "margin: 0px" to get it to work (although I understand purists prefer to leave out the "px" when the value is 0).

Comment: ohh yes you can.. i have an habit of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by default margins on the `body` and `h2` elements.

All you need is `margin-top: 0;` on these two elements.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;          /* Remove top margin from body */
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigationtext h2 {
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#navigation {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #009245;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;         /* Remove top margin from h2 */
}

#content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navigation" class="navigationtext">
    <h2><a href="">domain</a><br> the home page of First Last</h2>
    <p><a href="/about/">About</a></p>
    <p><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></p>
    <p><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></p>
    <div class="copyright">Copyright</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content/text goes here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Chava G, for your interest in my question and your help. I selected the previous post as the answer because I read that one first, but I really do appreciate your help. Thanks again. --Nick